# Application doesn't register with Growl

Tags: macos, cocoa, growl

I am trying to implement Growl into my Mac application. When running the application in debug mode, everything works perfectly and I am able to register the application with Growl and show notifications. When archiving and distributing the application, it does not register with Growl.

Does anyone know why this is?

When building for archiving I would get the following warning:

> warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed.

Then I set **Strip Debug Symbols During Copy** to **No** for both debug and release. This removed the warning. I don't know if this has anything to do with the application not registering with Growl when distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with Growl. It was due to some code failing causing a connection to a server not to be established and thereby my notifications would not arrive at the user.